# Manipulation of json files that are in git azure

Tags: reactjs, json, .net, git, azure

I have an assignment which basically is changing values in a json file that is in Azure git. It was straightforward changing a file in Github repo with the github libraries but Im kinda lost with Azure. Can anyone point some directions please? Im supposed to use .net and react, I open up a form and type in the new value and the script will do the magic upon submitting.

I tried some things with chatgpt. It suggested Newton framework for handling json files but couldnt see it through.

Comment: Are you asking about the git part (clone > make some changes > add > commit > push)? Or is your question about how to modify a json file?

Comment: I was asking abt modifying a json file without cloning the repo.

Comment: @bxn0 Hi, Is it the Github repo or Azure devops repos?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai hi, its azure repos

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the System.Text.Json namespace in .NET Core to work with JSON instead of Newtonsoft.Json. Here’s how you can modify to use System.Text.Json instead:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private static readonly string personalAccessToken = "YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN";
    private static readonly string repositoryUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/YOUR_ORGANIZATION/YOUR_PROJECT/_apis/git/repositories/YOUR_REPOSITORY/items?path=YOUR_JSON_FILE.json&api-version=6.0-preview.1";

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Set up HTTP client with authentication
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalAccessToken}")));

        try
        {
            // Read JSON content
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(repositoryUrl);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Modify JSON content (for example, update a property)
            // Here, we'll just add a timestamp to the JSON
            using JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonContent);
            using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using Utf8JsonWriter writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(ms, new JsonWriterOptions { Indented = true });

            writer.WriteStartObject();
            foreach (JsonProperty property in doc.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);
                property.Value.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            writer.WritePropertyName("lastModified");
            writer.WriteStringValue(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndObject();
            writer.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;

            // Update JSON file
            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            response = await client.PutAsync(repositoryUrl, stringContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            Console.WriteLine("JSON file updated successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

This modified example utilizes System.Text.Json for parsing and modifying the JSON content instead of Newtonsoft.Json. Make sure to include the necessary using directives and replace the placeholders with your actual values.

Comment: thanks, looks cleaner than those i tried but im looking for a way without cloning the repo